# how do i test apps on an htc thunderbolt

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, adb, htc-thunderbolt

I have been developing an android app, and i wanted to test it out on a real phone. I recently bought an htc thunderbolt to try it out in. The problem is, that my computer won't install the adb driver. What do i need to do to get it to work? The ide i am using is eclipse, the computer is windows 7 home primium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices under windows need their drivers.

You can get Google ones from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#Win7) and other vendors from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html).

Comment: Doesn't the top of that page specifically indicate that the Google USB driver is only for the ADP, Nexus One, and Nexus S phones...?

Comment: True, I just edited my answer with the correct link for other vendors.

Answer (score 4):

Install HTC Sync from HTC's website (this includes phone drivers). Windows should then detect your phone without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After Installing the Device driver your device will detect.

later goto command prompt and write the command

adb install

eg. adb install e:\test.apk

this will install the apk file to your device

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, you always can pass the .apk to the microSD of the phone simply with a pull from the DDMS.

I tried this with a Huawei mobile and it worked fine.